# Why does my data binding not work if the control is created in a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to bind data returned from my database to a combo box which I have declared inside a class and will be returning that combo box to the calling form.  The problem I am having is the data binding isn't working, I've verified data is being returned but when I assign the data to the data source property its like the binding never happened.  Is what I'm attempting to do not possible?

Here is the code in my class which returns the combo box to the calling form:

```
public ComboBox LoadCategoryData()
    {
        ComboBox cbx = new ComboBox();


        FindCategoryRequest request = new FindCategoryRequest();
        Service service = ServiceFactory.CreateService();
        FindCategoryResponse response = service.FindCategories(request);

        CategoryView viewItem = new CategoryView();
        viewItem.Name = "Select Category";
        IList<CategoryView> categories = response.Categories.ToList();
        categories.Insert(0, viewItem);
        cbx.DataSource = categories;
        cbx.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbx.ValueMember = "Id";

        return cbx;
    }
```

Comment: It should work, although I have doubts on that method returning a combobox to begin with...

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you're actually doing something with the combo box. For example adding it to some container control

Answer (score 1):

Created sample application from your code, it was working fine for me.

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var test = LoadCategoryData();
        this.Controls.Add(test);
    }

    public ComboBox LoadCategoryData()
    {
        ComboBox cbx = new ComboBox();
        CategoryView viewItem = new CategoryView();
        viewItem.Name = "Select Category";
        IList<CategoryView> categories = new List<CategoryView>() { new CategoryView() { Name = "Item1", Id = 1 } };
        categories.Insert(0, viewItem);
        cbx.DataSource = categories;
        cbx.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbx.ValueMember = "Id";

        return cbx;
    }
}

public class CategoryView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```